# How to redirect index.php pages

Tags: redirect, opencart

How to redirect
`/index.php?route=blog/blog` to `/blog`
and
`index.php?route=information/contact` to `/contact`

The site is on Opencart 2.3.
I tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?route=blog/blog$ /blog [R=301,L]
```

I've come to the point where pages open in both ways, but don't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against query string (anything that goes after `?` in URL) in pattern of a `RewriteRule` . You need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable using a `RewriteCond` directive

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=[^/]+/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```